# How to play even background mode using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

Audio Live Streaming Service using IIS7 is prepared.
Audio Live streaming server setting is very complex, but have succeeded.

I obtained a URL for streaming like this(@"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/liveStream.isml/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8").

My using code is unexpectedly simple.

```
   self.theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/liveStream.isml/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8"]; 

   if(moviePlayer == nil)
   {
       moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
   } 
    [moviePlayer play];
```

Hm... I can't control music player as I wished.

Question is like this.

I don't want to stop to play music even though backgroundMode.

Please tell me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: awesome question .... that's  why i am giving up vote

Answer (score 3):

please check in only  device.I have also done in my Application. My code is given below.i am talking about **iOS5**

**And in plist i made an array named "Required background mode" and insert an item in array name, "App Plays Audio".**  some times **URL problem** is occurs check this URL [MPMoviePlayer sound working in Simulators and ipad device, but not Working in iPhone Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408211/mpmovieplayer-sound-working-in-simulators-and-ipad-device-but-not-working-in-ip/9425552#9425552)

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad 
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
     UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

}
```

Comment: What this last two lines do? they really make my app works =)

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

Comment: when application goes to background at that time task should be identified Eg:obj-->"newTaskId"(last but-one line) and come to last line it will take one most important responsibility that is ,when application goes to background ,application had been running ,like audio player @jmeinik