# MPMoviePlayer sound working in Simulators and ipad device, but not Working in iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a problem with MPMoviePlayerController, i.e. I am playing the live stream url in (m3u8 format) MPMoviePlayer like below:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioUrl];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(loadStateDidChange:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:player];
        if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
        {
            // Set movie player layout

            [player setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
            [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly];
            [player setFullscreen:YES];
            [player prepareToPlay];
            [player play];

        }
    }
```

It is working in both simulators & iPad device with ios 5 version, but it is not giving the audio in any iPhone device i have.

Please help me out...
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mr simham ... check this below url it help for us becoZ

1. Call  stream-url within mobile safari. If that has the same results, then your code is correct and the stream is not. It would be an incorrectly encoded audio stream then.
2. it depends on bandwidth also below ref url regards to bandwidth check it once.... u r ref Stream URL prepare,according to BandWith

REFERENCE URL:

- http://wfmu.org/ssaudionet.shtml
- [APPLE](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html)

Comment: ya, it's awesome. Now i got what exactly i need. Thank you nag.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a deprecated `MPMovieControlMode` (`MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly`) towards the `controlStyle` property which is expecting a `MPMovieControlStyle`.

Additionally, your code is missing the part that assigns the `MPMoviePlayerController.view` towards any superview and also its sizing is missing.

Last but I guess most importantly for you, I am guessing that the iPhone you are trying it with has set the volume all the way down to silence. Or, maybe the audio-routing is not set towards speaker-output. For the latter, make sure you are not setting up the audio session incorrectly anywhere else in your App. When in doubt, try fiddling with the `useApplicationAudioSession` property. Try setting it towards `NO` and see if that changes your results.

If all above fails, then one additional check would be to call the stream-url within mobile safari. If that has the same results, then your code is correct and the stream is not. It would be an incorrectly encoded audio stream then.

Comment: I have already tried all the options. But one more apple url working fine. Why i'm not getting Mr. Till?

Comment: Ya, nice advise Mr. Till. It's not working in safari browser also. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your iPhone is on loudspeaker mode or not -

if not than set it using this-

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

Comment: all settings about audio are perfectly set in iPhone device. But the problem is "One more url (apple url) is working fine". After searching more and more, i just assuming that it may be BANDWIDTH related problem.if u know about BANDWIDTH concept, then plz let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the iPhone is in silent mode. To play audio even in silent mode, add the following code in **AppDelegate's** ***application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:***

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```