# Keep play MPMoviePlayerController after home button touch

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
MPMoviePlayerController vodPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:httpUrl]];
[vodPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)];
[self.view addSubview:vodPlayer.view];
[vodPlayer play];
```

When home button touch, the player was stopped..
I want to keep play when home button touch.
How to solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292421/how-to-play-even-background-mode-using-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)First of all MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated so try avoid using it.
2)If you are playing video, then there is no need of playing video when app is moved to background.

- Lets free the resources for next or other application if there is no use of it.

3)Use AVPLayer for playing video/Audio.
4)if you want to continue playing media in background mode, You must enable background mode in info.plist file.

[image]

Comment: I try using this, but when I goes to background, player is stop.

Comment: are playing video?

Comment: video will pause playing when application is being sent to background.

Comment: I want to play only video's sound directly, but I touch home button, then sound is pause.